# Z-index issue in mozila firefox, in a css only page

Tags: css, z-index

I know this has been asked many times, and I have been searching for the answer in a lot of places but I can't seem to fix my code. Thank you for reading this because I'm going crazy here! First I had a different z-index problem with safari, than another with explorer, but now the z-index problem I'm having with mozila I can't fix in any way. I code in chrome, where it seems to work perfectly (for me it seems at least!)

I believe now it works more or less fine in most browsers but not on mozila. The idea of the page is to make (only with CSS because that's the only language supported by the website) a flipping book of several pages. I see some examples around of CSS only flipping cards (only one page), but not a book of more than one page. So I essentially overlap several "cards", in order to give this effect. You can see the demo from codepen here: pkrein/pen/qBOewem

Btw I do know this code is not as clean as it could be, but that's the way I figured to make a fuction like that works only with CSS, and I hope it will make sense for you.

Ok, so the matter is, the content inside the book pages is not "scrollable" on firefox. I guess this is indeed a z-index problem, because when I move any page outside the book, that is, from behind the rest of the content, it scrolls fine.

Let me know if I can give any more info that could help you understand my issue!

Comment: can you include a code pen link to your code, you tell us what you have already tried(by providing code)

Comment: Here is the link: https://codepen.io/pkrein/pen/qBOewem 
But it doesn't seem to look fine on codepen as it looks on the webpage! I will tell you what I've tried in a sec

Comment: What I have tried:

Comment: What I have tried: (1) to change the position of elements, from fixed to absolute. (2) to use negative z-index values. (3) remove z-index values from .flapfront and #flapback. (4) delete all the divs inside the flaps and only leave text, to see if it will scroll. (5) delete the top flap to see if the bottom will scroll, because the top flap scrolls. I discovered if I do that, the flap that is on top always scrolls. (6) change the order the flaps appear on the html. The flap that appears first in the html will scroll.

Comment: I have also tried not using any negative z index value!

Answer (score 0):

I figured a possible solution for this. It's not quite the solution for the problem itself but it's something that can make what I want to do work.

The problem was: (what I had to remove in order to make it work):
(1) The div #content-holder holding all the text inside the flap
(2) The div .preparation-text inside the .preparation (that's the text I want to scroll). That was a scrolling div (.preparation) inside a non-scrolling div (.preparation-text). I always add a scrolling div inside a non-scrolling div in order to hide the scrollbar, by adding a high padding-right to the inside div. I know I can use code to hide the scrollbar but it do not work in all browsers.

How I fixed:
(1) I just removed the #content-holedr divs, since it was not strictly necessary.
(2) I removed the .preparation-text and transformed .preparation into a scrolling div. Then I just covered the scrollbar with an image of the same size and colors as the background (a print of the layout).